# Need to store months name in list starting from September to August

Tags: java

I want to store month name in a list i.e from September-August, I found a code here for storing month name in list but not getting how to store it from september-August. I tried Move last element to front of a given Linked List algorithm found on GeeksForGeeks[Algorithm link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/move-last-element-to-front-of-a-given-linked-list/) but that not working as i want.

Code i'm using:

```
    private void monthList () {
        List<String> listOfMonth = new LinkedList<>();
        String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
        for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
            String month = months[i];
            //System.out.println("month = " + month);
            listOfMonth .add(months[i]);
            LinkedList list  = new LinkedList();

        }
        System.out.println(listOfMonth);
    }
```

Regards

Comment: So you need it over a 11 month period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question you were pretty close. Create an array of offsets, then use that to compute the entry you want from `months`. And you don't need that inner `LinkedList`. Like,

```
List<String> listOfMonth = new LinkedList<>();
int[] offset = { 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
for (int i = 0; i < offset.length; i++) {
    listOfMonth.add(months[offset[i] - 1]);
}
System.out.println(listOfMonth);
```

Outputs

```
[Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug]
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the months of the year, shifted by 8 months, using Java 8+:

```
List<String> listOfMonth = new ArrayList<>();
for (int m = 0; m < 12; m++)
    listOfMonth.add(Month.of((m + 8) % 12 + 1).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US));
System.out.println(listOfMonth);
```

**Output**

```
[September, October, November, December, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August]
```

**Imports**

```
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly different approach, you could simply make use of the date/time API and a `DateTimeFormatter`, for example...

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM", Locale.UK);
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.SEPTEMBER, 1);
LocalDate endDate = ld.plusYears(1);
List<String> months = new LinkedList<>();
while (ld.isBefore(endDate)) {
    months.add(ld.format(format));
    ld = ld.plusMonths(1);
}
```

Which generate a list containing...

```
September
October
November
December
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
```

Comment: Using full `java.time.LocalDate` when `java.time.Month` can do it seems a bit overkill.

Comment: @Andreas Possibly, but I just answered the question the way that I would have tried had I tried to solve the problem :P - You should not that I also need the year, as I set the end date a year in advance (I be simple :P)

Comment: @VineetSingh Just one more way to skin the cat ;)

Answer (score 0):

This could look like this.

```
List<String> listOfMonth = new LinkedList<>();
String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
for (int index = 0; index < 12; index++) {
    listOfMonth.add(months[(index + 8) % 12]);
}
```

Here, you take an index from 0 to 12.  You add 8 to get the appropriate entry number from the array of month names - when index is 0, you want entry number 8 in the array, which is `Sep`, because arrays are numbered from 0.

Doing the `% 12` part makes sure that you only look up indexes between 0 and 11.